# Template for class returning elements of Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE>

Tags: c++, rcpp

Consider the following class that does absolutely nothing:

```
class MyNumVec
{
  private:
    const NumericVector& x;
  public:
    MyNumVec(const NumericVector& y) : x(y) {}
    double operator[](int i) const { // here
      return x[i];
    }
    operator NumericVector() const { return x; }
};
```

I would like to make it more general and use template for it so that I'll be working with any `Vector<RTYPE>` instead of numeric vectors only, but the problem is the line marked by comment since I must declare output type. I tried using `auto` type from C++11, but it doesn't work ("`'auto' return without trailing return type`"). How can this be translated to template working with `Vector` of any type?

Comment: For reference, the conventional way to do this in C++98 is to template the class on the underlying `SEXPTYPE` and use `Rcpp::traits::storage_type` to determine the atomic type. [For example](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/a6c154ae18d2a5cc8dcc3af06da01ea6#file-vector-template-cpp).

Comment: @nrussell could you write the gist as an answer instead? It's a viable alternative to the `auto` example. I'm a bit afraid it may get lost in the mess of SO otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to stick to C++98, the usual idiom is to use an integer template parameter to represent [the different `SEXPTYPE`s](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs). When dealing with `Rcpp::*Vector` (or `Rcpp::*Matrix`) you are typically only concerned with 5 of these:

```r
# Integer Value SEXPTYPE  R Vector     Rcpp Vector
#            10   LGLSXP   logical   LogicalVector
#            13   INTSXP   integer   IntegerVector
#            14  REALSXP   numeric   NumericVector
#            15  CPLXSXP   complex   ComplexVector
#            16   STRSXP character CharacterVector
```

Having done this, there are standard metaprogramming tools for commonly needed transformations in the `Rcpp::traits` namespace:

- `SEXPTYPE` -> POD¹ type: [`storage_type`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/traits/storage_type.h)

  - `Rcpp::traits::storage_type<REALSXP>::type` -> `double`
  - `Rcpp::traits::storage_type<INTSXP>::type` -> `int`
  - etc.
- POD¹ type -> `SEXPTYPE`: [`r_sexptype_traits`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/traits/r_sexptype_traits.h)

  - `Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<double>::rtype` -> 14 (`REALSXP`)
  - `Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<int>::rtype` -> 13 (`INTSXP`)
  - etc.

¹`storage_type<STRSXP>::type` yields `SEXP` (specifically, a `CHARSXP`), and while *technically* a POD type, it differs from the other simple vector types in that its atomic unit is an opaque pointer (a `SEXP`), and not, e.g. a `const char*` or `std::string` as might be expected.

---

An uninteresting example, using `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` for conciseness:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

template <int RTYPE>
class MyNumVec {
public:
    typedef Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> vec_t;
    typedef typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type storage_t;

private:
    const vec_t& x;

public:
    MyNumVec(const vec_t& y)
        : x(y)
    {}

    storage_t operator[](int i) const
    { return x[i]; }

    operator vec_t() const
    { return x; }
};

template <int RTYPE>
Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> get_first_elem_impl(const Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE>& vec)
{
    MyNumVec<RTYPE> tmp(vec);
    return Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE>::create(tmp[0]);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RObject get_first_elem(Rcpp::RObject x) {
    RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(get_first_elem_impl, x);
}
```

---

```r
get_first_elem(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
# [1] TRUE

get_first_elem(1L:5L)
# [1] 1

get_first_elem(1:5 + 0.5)
# [1] 1.5

get_first_elem(1:5 + 2i)
# [1] 1+2i

get_first_elem(letters[1:5])
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: Fantastic post as usual @nrussell.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` return type deduction without a *trailing return type* is a C++14 language feature. In C++11, you can use `auto` as long as you add a *trailing return type*:

```
auto operator[](int i) const -> decltype(x[i]) { 
    return x[i];
}
```

In the code above, `auto` will be "replaced" with the type of `x[i]`.

Comment: For what it is worth, this last weekend I just wrote up a [Rcpp Gallery piece on Rcpp and C++11, C++14, and C++17](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-and-c++11-c++14-c++17/) which happens to show `auto` as a return type.  With C++14, of course.