# Extending Rcpp function to input vector of any type

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have following function which does a simple loop on `NumericVector` and returns `int` type value.

```
  Rcpp::cppFunction({'
  int calc_streak( NumericVector x, int i1, int i2){
  int cur_streak=1;

  if (NumericVector::is_na(x[0])){
    cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
  } else {
    cur_streak = 1;
  }

  for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
    if( x[ j ] == x[ j-1 ]){
      cur_streak += 1;

    } else if(NumericVector::is_na( x[ j ] )){
      cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

    } else {
      cur_streak = 1;

    }
  }
  return cur_streak;
}
"})

calc_streak(c(1,1,1,1),i1=0,i2=3)
# [1] 4
```

Function works fine for me but the real issue is when **I'm trying to extend this functionality on other input-types**. I've been searching on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363850/template-for-class-returning-elements-of-rcppvectorrtype) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823915/how-can-i-handle-vectors-without-knowing-the-type-in-rcpp), but those examples doesn't work in my case or I don't know how to use examples properly. I've tried few methods dealing with unknown input type, and none was successful in my case.
Three examples below

---

1. The simplest one inspired by [this](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/) - created main function which run one of previously defined functions depending on type of argument `TYPEOF(x)`. **This function returns expected value for `integer` and `numeric`. For `character` session crashes**

   ```
   Rcpp::cppFunction('
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   using namespace Rcpp;

   int streak_run_int(IntegerVector x, int i1, int i2){
     int cur_streak=1;

     if (IntegerVector::is_na(x[0])){
       cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
     } else {
      cur_streak = 1;
     }

     for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
       if( x[ j ] == x[ j-1 ]){
        cur_streak += 1;

       } else if(IntegerVector::is_na( x[ j ] )){
         cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

       } else {
         cur_streak = 1;

       }
     }
     return cur_streak;
   }

   int streak_run_char(CharacterVector x, int i1, int i2){
     int cur_streak=1;

     if (CharacterVector::is_na(x[0])){
       cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
     } else {
       cur_streak = 1;
     }

     for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
       if( x[ j ] == x[ j-1 ]){
       cur_streak += 1;

       } else if(CharacterVector::is_na( x[ j ] )){
         cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

       } else {
         cur_streak = 1;

       }
     }
     return cur_streak;
   }


     // [[Rcpp::export]]
   int streak_run4(SEXP x, int i1, int i2) {
     switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
     case INTSXP: {
       return streak_run_int(as<IntegerVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     case STRSXP: {
       return streak_run_char(as<CharacterVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     default: { return 0; }
     }
   }
   ')

   # expected results for int and real - for character session crashes
   streak_run4( c(1,1,1,1),i1=0, i2=3)
   streak_run4( as.integer(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
   streak_run4( as.character(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
   ```

---

2. Second function has exactly the same idea, but using template instead of defining multiple functions. Same results as above - **session crash on `character` input**

   ```
   Rcpp::cppFunction('
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   using namespace Rcpp;

   namespace impl {

     template <int RTYPE>
       int streak_run_impl(const Vector<RTYPE>& x, int i1, int i2)
     {
       int cur_streak=1;

       if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[0])){
         cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
       } else {
         cur_streak = 1;
       }

       for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
         if( x[ j ] == x[ j-1 ]){
           cur_streak += 1;

         } else if(Vector<RTYPE>::is_na( x[ j ] )){
           cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

         } else {
           cur_streak = 1;

         }
       }
       return cur_streak;
       }

   }

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   int streak_run3(SEXP x, int i1, int i2) {
     switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
     case INTSXP: {
       return impl::streak_run_impl(as<IntegerVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     case REALSXP: {
       return impl::streak_run_impl(as<NumericVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     case STRSXP: {
       return impl::streak_run_impl(as<CharacterVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     case LGLSXP: {
       return impl::streak_run_impl(as<LogicalVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     case CPLXSXP: {
       return impl::streak_run_impl(as<ComplexVector>(x), i1, i2);
     }
     default: {
       return 0;
     }
     }
   }
   ')

   streak_run3( c(1,1,1,1),i1=0, i2=3)
   streak_run3( as.integer(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
   streak_run3( as.character(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
   ```

---

3. Another one is inspired by [this article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-return-macros/), and this time I wasn't even able to compile C++ function, while having an error `use of overloaded operator '==' is ambiguous`. Anyway, after examining two above examples, I don't expect any other result.

   ```
   Rcpp::cppFunction('
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   using namespace Rcpp;

   class streak_run2_impl {
     private:
     int i1;
     int i2;

     public:
     streak_run2_impl(int i1, int i2) : i1(i1), i2(i2) {}

     template <int RTYPE>
     IntegerVector operator()(const Vector<RTYPE>& x)
     {

       int cur_streak=1;

       if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[0])){
       cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
       } else {
       cur_streak = 1;
       }

       for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
         if( x[ j ] == x[ j-1 ] ){
           cur_streak += 1;

         } else if(Vector<RTYPE>::is_na( x[ j ] )){

           cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

         } else {
           cur_streak = 1;
         }
       }
       return cur_streak;
     }
   };


   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   RObject streak_run2(RObject x, int i1 = 0, int i2=6){
     RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(streak_run2_impl(i1, i2), x);
   }
   ')
   ```

---

**So my question is:**
How to properly define this function to obtain results for input vector of any R class?
I would be obliged for any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main error in examples are that you start your loop at `j = 0` so you call `operator[](-1)`. The following works for me. Make the following `func.cpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
int streak_run_impl(const Vector<RTYPE>& x, int i1, int i2)
{
  int cur_streak = 1;

  if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[0])){
    cur_streak = NA_INTEGER;
  } else {
    cur_streak = 1;
  }

  for(int j = std::max(i1, 1) /* have to start at one at least */; 
      j < std::min(i2 + 1, (int)x.size()) /* check size of x */; ++j){
    if(x[j] == x[j - 1]){
      cur_streak += 1;

    } else if(Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[j])){
      cur_streak = NA_INTEGER;

    } else {
      cur_streak = 1;

    }
  }
  return cur_streak;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int streak_run3(SEXP x, int i1, int i2) {
  switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
    case INTSXP: {
      return streak_run_impl(as<IntegerVector>(x), i1, i2);
    }
    case REALSXP: {
      return streak_run_impl(as<NumericVector>(x), i1, i2);
    }
    case STRSXP: {
      return streak_run_impl(as<CharacterVector>(x), i1, i2);
    }
    case LGLSXP: {
      return streak_run_impl(as<LogicalVector>(x), i1, i2);
    }
    case CPLXSXP: {
      return streak_run_impl(as<ComplexVector>(x), i1, i2);
    }
    default: {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then run this R script with the working directory set to that of the `.cpp` file

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("func.cpp")

streak_run3(c(1,1,1,1), i1=0, i2=3)
streak_run3(as.integer(c(1,1,1,1)), i1=0, i2=3)
streak_run3(as.character(c(1,1,1,1)), i1=0, i2=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, nice post! Unfortunately, none of the above resources you've linked are relevant to your problem as its due to a completely different error that wasn't picked up in the prototype function.  For *why* the prototype returned a valid value on call, well that is pure luck.

As @BenjaminChristoffersen pointed out, the code is running into an [undefined behavior (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to an [out-of-bounds (OOB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking) error occurring. His solution will effectively "fix" the problem.

However, to diagnose this in the future on your own, switch from using the element accessor `[]` to `()`, which checks that the element you are requesting is within the bounds. e.g. Is *j* in *0* to *n - 1*?

e.g.

```
  if (Vector<RTYPE>::is_na( x( 0 ) )){
  // ------------------------^---^

    cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();
  } else {
    cur_streak = 1;
  }

  for(int j = i1; j <= i2 ; ++j) {
    if( x( j ) == x( j-1 )){
      // ^---^-----^-----^
      cur_streak += 1;

    } else if(Vector<RTYPE>::is_na( x( j ) )){
      // --------------------------- ^   ^

      cur_streak = NumericVector::get_na();

    } else {
      cur_streak = 1;

    }
  }
```

Running the same commands then give:

```
streak_run3( c(1,1,1,1),i1=0, i2=3)
```

Output:

```
Error in streak_run3(c(1, 1, 1, 1), i1 = 0, i2 = 3) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index=-1; extent=4].
```

Input:

```
streak_run3( as.integer(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
```

Output:

```
Error in streak_run3(as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1)), i1 = 0, i2 = 3) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index=-1; extent=4].
```

Input:

```
streak_run3( as.character(c(1,1,1,1)),i1=0, i2=3)
```

Output:

```
Error in streak_run3(as.character(c(1, 1, 1, 1)), i1 = 0, i2 = 3) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index=-1; extent=4].
```