# Return subset of a given SEXP without knowing the actual internal data type

Tags: c++, r, subset, rcpp

I am writing an [R package to provide debug helper functions](https://github.com/aryoda/R_CppDebugHelper) for `gdb` to print variable values of `R`s `SEXP` and `Rcpp`s data types.

C/C++ is a strongly typed language but I want to avoid querying the internal data type of the `SEXP` and use a bunch of `if`s for hard-coded dispatching.

**How could I implement a generic subset function using an index range via a function signature like this:**

```
SEXP dbg_subset(SEXP x, R_xlen_t index_from, R_xlen_t index_to);
```

One possible solution would be to write the above function for each possible signature, eg.
for `INTSXP`, `LGLSXP`, `STRSXP`... but I am lazy ;-)

Note: I can't use C++ templates because the linker would only create the template instances for the data types used in my C++ code (which are not the same as in the "library under debugging") and `gdb`
is no compiler which could create the missing template instances "on-the-fly" when C++ expressions are entered to query variables.

**Edit:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829440) (but it is based on templates which I want to avoid):

Comment: See e.g. https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/

Comment: Isn't the linked answer almost exactly what you are looking for? Note that `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` will instantiate the template for all(?) R data types, which is why I had to create an explicit implementation for complex here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223792/8416610

Comment: @RalfStubner Now that I understand the implementation of the `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` macro as a reusable dispatch code I am sure my linked answer would have given me enough background to solve my problem. Is was just stopping to try it out because it uses templates which I wanted to avoid due to missing instance problems (which in fact are solved when using `RCPP_RETURN*`). Your answer is nevertheless very precious because it shows how to subset generically!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a C++ template together with the [`RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR`](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-return-macros/) macro. This macro will make sure that the template is instantiated for all(?) R data types:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

template <int RTYPE>
Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> debug_subset_impl(Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> x,
                                      R_xlen_t index_from,
                                      R_xlen_t index_to){
    // range [index_from, index_to)
    Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> subset(index_to - index_from);
    std::copy(x.cbegin() + index_from, x.cbegin() + index_to, subset.begin());
    // special case for factors == INTSXP with "class" and "levels" attribute
    if (x.hasAttribute("levels")){
        subset.attr("class") = x.attr("class");
        subset.attr("levels") = x.attr("levels");
    }
    return subset;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP dbg_subset(SEXP x, R_xlen_t index_from, R_xlen_t index_to){
    // 1-based -> 0-based
    RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR(debug_subset_impl, x, index_from - 1, index_to - 1);
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
dbg_subset(1:100, 3, 6)
dbg_subset(runif(100), 3, 6)
dbg_subset(letters, 3, 6)
dbg_subset(as.factor(letters), 3, 6)
*/
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('58965423.cpp')

> set.seed(42)

> dbg_subset(1:100, 3, 6)
[1] 3 4 5

> dbg_subset(runif(100), 3, 6)
[1] 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455

> dbg_subset(letters, 3, 6)
[1] "c" "d" "e"

> dbg_subset(as.factor(letters), 3, 6)
[1] c d e
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: THX a lot for taking the time to provide non-trivial implementation, that is what I've been looking for!

Comment: Just a view comments (for other readers who want to use the code) on how I extended the code: `std::copy` copies from begin to end minus 1 so the last element was missing (easy to fix); range checking of the indexes is required to prevent segfaults; attributes should always be kept (at least R does); `data.frame` subsetting returns the wrong result (subsets the cols, not the rows, since `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` does only know lists but no `data.frame`)